# Find partial fractions of $\frac{x^2-1}{x^4+1}$

Tags: partial-fractions

I tried to figure out how WA found the partial fractions of $\frac{x^2-1}{x^4+1}$:

[image]

Help is Appreciated.

Comment: $x^4+1=x^4+2x^2+1-2x^2=(x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt 2x)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from
$(x^2+x\sqrt{2}+1)(x^2-x\sqrt{2}+1)
=(x^2+1)^2-(x\sqrt{2})^2
=x^4+2x^2+1-2x^2
=x^4+1
$
so that
$\frac{x^2-1}{x^4+1}
=\frac{x^2-1}{(x^2+x\sqrt{2}+1)(x^2-x\sqrt{2}+1)}
$.

Then use partial fractions.

Comment: Neat factorization, isn't it?